# reactjs, json, image loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs -- I am looping through a json object - and I am trying to add the image path from the json object.

So this is how it is currently hard coded in the component.

```
import HowImage1 from '../../img/home/works_emp_01.png'

then in the component its rendered like this {HowImage1}
```

but in the json obj

```
        {
            "image" : "/img/home/works_emp_01.png"
        }
```

now is this falling down - because I need to wrap the path when including it in the component?

---

ok json object.

```
{
  "langs": [{
    "lang": "de",
    "lines": {
        "howTiles": [{
            "title": "So funktioniert die Zusammenarbeit",
            "subhead" : "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt in wenigen Sekunden aus",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title": "Projekt ausschreiben", 
                    "description": "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt aus und zeigen Sie es einer handverlesenen Gruppe von Fachexperten",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "15 Minuten Video-Gespräch", 
                    "description": "Führen Sie eine unverbindliche Unterhaltung mit 3 vorselektierten Anwälten",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Transparente Zusammenarbeit", 
                    "description": "Erhalten Sie einen bindenden Kostenvoranschlag und arbeiten Sie online zusammen",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                }
            ],
            "button": {"title": "Kostenlose Angebote erhalten", "url": "/de/projekt-ausschreibung"}
        }]
    },
    "pageURL": "/de/dienstleistungen",
    "urls":  {
      "servicePages": [{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"},{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"}],
      "otherPages": [{"other_page1": "other page"},{"other_page2": "other page 1"}]
    }
  }, {
    "lang": "en",
    "lines": {
        "howTiles": [{
            "title": "How it works",
            "subhead" : "Get started with your projects in a few seconds",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title": "Post your project", 
                    "description": "Post your project privately to a cohort of qualified professionals",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "15 minute video interviews", 
                    "description": "Have 3 non-binding interviews with pre-sected lawyers",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Transparent collaboration", 
                    "description": "Receive a fixed price quote and work online",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                }
            ],
            "button": {"title": "Get free quotes", "url": "/en/project-post"}
        }]
    },
    "pageURL": "/en/services",
    "urls":  {
      "servicePages": [{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"},{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"}],
      "otherPages": [{"other_page1": "other page"},{"other_page2": "other page 1"}]
    }
  }]
}
```

react component.. also getting a bug on the index === 0 ? part " error '?' should be placed at the beginning of the line operator-linebreak"

```
import React from 'react'
import HowImage1 from '../../img/home/works_emp_01.png'
import HowImage2 from '../../img/home/features_emp_icon_15.png'
import HowImage3 from '../../img/home/about_us_icon_03.png'

const HowTiles = (props) => {
  const lang = props.lang

  return (
    <section className='border__transparent--top background--white grid__row--offset--120'>
      <header>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
          <div className='small-58 medium-55 large-40 small-centered columns'>
            <h1 className='text--center--small text--center smooth-font'><font><font className=''>{lang.howTiles[0].title}</font></font></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--5'>
          <div className='small-55 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
            <h2 className='text--center text--center smooth-font'><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].subhead}</font></font></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--30'>
          <div className='small-58 medium-55 small-centered columns hor-line--thin--dark-grey'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
        <div className='small-55 medium-58 large-58 small-centered columns background--white--small border__transparent--top'>
          <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                <div className='relative-container'>
                  <img className='centered' src={HowImage1} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                  <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>Project</font></font></h3>
                  <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Write out your project and show it to a hand-picked group of experts</font></font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
              <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='small-60 grid__row--offset--40 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                <div className='relative-container'>
                  <img className='centered' src={HowImage2} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                  <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>15 minutes of video conversation</font></font></h3>
                  <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Conduct a non-committal conversation with 3 preselected attorneys</font></font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='small-60 grid__row--offset--40 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                <div className='relative-container'>
                  <img className='centered' src={HowImage3} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                  <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>Transparent cooperation</font></font></h3>
                  <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Get a binding quote and work together online</font></font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='row grid__row--offset--70 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--80'>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

      <div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
        <div className='small-55 medium-58 large-58 small-centered columns background--white--small border__transparent--top'>
          {
            lang.howTiles[0].items.map(function (item, index) {
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
                  <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
                    <div className='row'>
                      <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                        <div className='relative-container'>
                          <img className='centered' src={item.image} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                          <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>{item.title}</font></font></h3>
                          <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>{item.description}</font></font></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {
                      index === 0 ?
                        <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
                          <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                            <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                            <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      : null
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }

          <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--80'>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

      <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
      <div className='row grid__row--offset--80 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
    </section>
  )
}

HowTiles.propTypes = {
  lang: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default HowTiles
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you show us the "loop" and how are you trying to include the image?

Comment: --- so here I am trying to loop through the json blob to create/replace the hardcoded part--- the image path is not coming out -- and I am getting an error with the condition part that will place a button under the first item

Comment: @ToddChaffee any suggestions?

Comment: @errata suggestions?

Comment: I've tried to add a const image 
inside the loop - but then it breaks a webpack?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948138/reactjs-getting-image-paths-from-json-to-render-in-a-component-during-a-loop

Comment: @TheOldCounty I am also pretty new to React, haven't use images at all with it... I'll try to take a look at your code today, hopefully will find some sort of solution :) In the meantime, can you please provide your Webpack config and even maybe package.json?

Comment: Well the webpack config and the package.json - isn't where the data is stored. I will see what I can share - but this is a near-pre-made react project

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing image import compete json and loop through that.

```
import HowImage1 from '../jsonpath'
```

Then loop through this json and get the image url from this.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
   super();
   //loop your json here and create json
 }

  render() {
    return <div>
      // use that variable here
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something like that -- but the image path is non-existant -- 
                          <img className='centered' src={item.image} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/home/works_emp_01.png  -- Cannot GET /img/home/works_emp_01.png

Comment: Are you using webpack or anything for bundling your code?

Comment: -- yes -- but the above example -- I am trying to put the content into the markup now - run from a json blob

Comment: What is the project hierarchy? where does "img" folder live ?

Comment: If you are bundling your code then put your image in the target folder where the bundle.js is. May be this will help. Request you to  provide some codepen or fiddle.

Comment: lives inside the src folder --- src/img

Comment: in the current component - its like this "import HowImage1 from '../../img/home/works_emp_01.png'"     -- so that component lives -- src/components/Services -- so that's why its going back to the root like that -- but the image renders that way as a data blob -- do I need to wrap a require or something around the json path? -- src={item.image} becomes src={require(item.image)}

Comment: @SaifMasadeh any suggestions?

Comment: @suyesh any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried to add a const image 
inside the loop - but then it breaks a webpack?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948138/reactjs-getting-image-paths-from-json-to-render-in-a-component-during-a-loop