# reactjs, images not loading from a json path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show images that are part of a json blob. Although struggling to dynamically generate the images.

```
{
  "langs": [{
    "lang": "de",
    "lines": {
        "howTiles": [{
            "title": "So funktioniert die Zusammenarbeit",
            "subhead" : "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt in wenigen Sekunden aus",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title": "Projekt ausschreiben", 
                    "description": "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt aus und zeigen Sie es einer handverlesenen Gruppe von Fachexperten",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "15 Minuten Video-Gespräch", 
                    "description": "Führen Sie eine unverbindliche Unterhaltung mit 3 vorselektierten Anwälten",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/features_emp_icon_15.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Transparente Zusammenarbeit", 
                    "description": "Erhalten Sie einen bindenden Kostenvoranschlag und arbeiten Sie online zusammen",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/about_us_icon_03.png"
                }
            ],
            "button": {"title": "Kostenlose Angebote erhalten", "url": "/de/projekt-ausschreibung"}
        }]
    },
    "pageURL": "/de/dienstleistungen",
    "urls":  {
      "servicePages": [{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"},{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"}],
      "otherPages": [{"other_page1": "other page"},{"other_page2": "other page 1"}]
    }
  }, {
    "lang": "en",
    "lines": {
        "howTiles": [{
            "title": "How it works",
            "subhead" : "Get started with your projects in a few seconds",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title": "Post your project", 
                    "description": "Post your project privately to a cohort of qualified professionals",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "15 minute video interviews", 
                    "description": "Have 3 non-binding interviews with pre-sected lawyers",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/features_emp_icon_15.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Transparent collaboration", 
                    "description": "Receive a fixed price quote and work online",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/about_us_icon_03.png"
                }
            ],
            "button": {"title": "Get free quotes", "url": "/en/project-post"}
        }]
    },
    "pageURL": "/en/services",
    "urls":  {
      "servicePages": [{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"},{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"}],
      "otherPages": [{"other_page1": "other page"},{"other_page2": "other page 1"}]
    }
  }]
}
```

I am able to create a const Image at the top of the loop - but when I try and put the dynamic path coming in from the json it fails.

```
      {
        lang.howTiles[0].items.map(function (item, index) {
          const path = item.image;
          const image = require('../../img/home/about_us_icon_03.png')
          // const image = require(item.image)
          // console.log('image', image)
          console.log('path', path)

          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
              <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                    <div className='relative-container'>
                      <img className='centered' src={image} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                      <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>{item.title}</font></font></h3>
                      <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>{item.description}</font></font></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {
                    index === 0
                      ? <div>
                        <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
                          <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                            <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                            <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      : null
                  }
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
```

// error when I uncomment the const require(image.path)

```
HowTiles.js:277 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (webpack:///./components/Services/HowTiles.js?:277:67)
    at eval (webpack:///./components/Services/HowTiles.js?:277:145)
    at Array.map (native)
    at HowTiles (webpack:///./components/Services/HowTiles.js?:274:32)
    at eval (webpack:///../~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:306:16)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (webpack:///../~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:75:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (webpack:///../~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:305:14)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (webpack:///../~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:280:21)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (webpack:///../~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:188:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (webpack:///../~/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js?:46:35)
```

other attempts

I am new to reactjs -- I am looping through a json object - and I am trying to add the image path from the json object.

So this is how it is currently hard coded in the component.

```
import HowImage1 from '../../img/home/works_emp_01.png'

then in the component its rendered like this {HowImage1}
```

but in the json obj

```
        {
            "image" : "/img/home/works_emp_01.png"
        }
```

now is this falling down - because I need to wrap the path when including it in the component?

---

ok json object.

```
{
  "langs": [{
    "lang": "de",
    "lines": {
        "howTiles": [{
            "title": "So funktioniert die Zusammenarbeit",
            "subhead" : "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt in wenigen Sekunden aus",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title": "Projekt ausschreiben", 
                    "description": "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt aus und zeigen Sie es einer handverlesenen Gruppe von Fachexperten",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "15 Minuten Video-Gespräch", 
                    "description": "Führen Sie eine unverbindliche Unterhaltung mit 3 vorselektierten Anwälten",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Transparente Zusammenarbeit", 
                    "description": "Erhalten Sie einen bindenden Kostenvoranschlag und arbeiten Sie online zusammen",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                }
            ],
            "button": {"title": "Kostenlose Angebote erhalten", "url": "/de/projekt-ausschreibung"}
        }]
    },
    "pageURL": "/de/dienstleistungen",
    "urls":  {
      "servicePages": [{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"},{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"}],
      "otherPages": [{"other_page1": "other page"},{"other_page2": "other page 1"}]
    }
  }, {
    "lang": "en",
    "lines": {
        "howTiles": [{
            "title": "How it works",
            "subhead" : "Get started with your projects in a few seconds",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "title": "Post your project", 
                    "description": "Post your project privately to a cohort of qualified professionals",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "15 minute video interviews", 
                    "description": "Have 3 non-binding interviews with pre-sected lawyers",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Transparent collaboration", 
                    "description": "Receive a fixed price quote and work online",
                    "image" : "../../img/home/works_emp_01.png"
                }
            ],
            "button": {"title": "Get free quotes", "url": "/en/project-post"}
        }]
    },
    "pageURL": "/en/services",
    "urls":  {
      "servicePages": [{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"},{"Medienrecht":"/medienrecht"}],
      "otherPages": [{"other_page1": "other page"},{"other_page2": "other page 1"}]
    }
  }]
}
```

react component.. also getting a bug on the index === 0 ? part " error '?' should be placed at the beginning of the line operator-linebreak"

```
import React from 'react'
import HowImage1 from '../../img/home/works_emp_01.png'
import HowImage2 from '../../img/home/features_emp_icon_15.png'
import HowImage3 from '../../img/home/about_us_icon_03.png'

const HowTiles = (props) => {
  const lang = props.lang

  return (
    <section className='border__transparent--top background--white grid__row--offset--120'>
      <header>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
          <div className='small-58 medium-55 large-40 small-centered columns'>
            <h1 className='text--center--small text--center smooth-font'><font><font className=''>{lang.howTiles[0].title}</font></font></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--5'>
          <div className='small-55 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
            <h2 className='text--center text--center smooth-font'><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].subhead}</font></font></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--30'>
          <div className='small-58 medium-55 small-centered columns hor-line--thin--dark-grey'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
        <div className='small-55 medium-58 large-58 small-centered columns background--white--small border__transparent--top'>
          <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                <div className='relative-container'>
                  <img className='centered' src={HowImage1} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                  <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>Project</font></font></h3>
                  <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Write out your project and show it to a hand-picked group of experts</font></font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
              <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='small-60 grid__row--offset--40 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                <div className='relative-container'>
                  <img className='centered' src={HowImage2} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                  <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>15 minutes of video conversation</font></font></h3>
                  <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Conduct a non-committal conversation with 3 preselected attorneys</font></font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='small-60 grid__row--offset--40 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                <div className='relative-container'>
                  <img className='centered' src={HowImage3} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                  <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>Transparent cooperation</font></font></h3>
                  <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Get a binding quote and work together online</font></font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='row grid__row--offset--70 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--80'>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

      <div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
        <div className='small-55 medium-58 large-58 small-centered columns background--white--small border__transparent--top'>
          {
            lang.howTiles[0].items.map(function (item, index) {
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
                  <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
                    <div className='row'>
                      <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                        <div className='relative-container'>
                          <img className='centered' src={item.image} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                          <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>{item.title}</font></font></h3>
                          <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>{item.description}</font></font></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {
                      index === 0 ?
                        <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
                          <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                            <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                            <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      : null
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }

          <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--80'>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

      <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
      <div className='row grid__row--offset--80 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
    </section>
  )
}

HowTiles.propTypes = {
  lang: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default HowTiles
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs, json, image loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940778/reactjs-json-image-loading)

Comment: It is - no one has provided a solution to it

Comment: The hardcoded image works because webpack can read that asset at build time and include it in the bundle. Any images you want to `require` will need to be in your webpack bundle. IMO don't bundle dynamic image assets.

Comment: @AndyGaskell how can I include the dynamic images -- cause really the images are content - how would i loop through the content in this way?

Comment: I would not bundle images this way. Put the images in a publicly accessible directory on your web server and reference them like you would any image, e.g. `<img src="/public/images/dynamic-image.png" />`.

Comment: @AndyGaskell - the images are accessible in that directory -- but the json is content driven -- I am replacing static html markup with json data -- so the text content is being looped over and replaced -- but how can I generate the image paths properly -- I don't want to do a mash of if/else -- hard coded image paths in the react component?

Comment: Essentially I want to delete the hardcoded variables at the top -- HowImage1 , HowImage2, HowImage3 -- and have those paths coming from the json string... cause I have a language switch here -- what if I use different thumbs for the German language? You see the problem right? Very keen to find a working solution here

Comment: `<img className='centered' src={item.image} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope -- what it is -- it doesn't like the image path -- so the image path can't be found -- those hardcoded images come out as data blobs you see -- its like I can't just shovel an image path in there

Comment: const image = require('../../img/home/about_us_icon_03.png')  -- renders an image -- which is like a data blob when you look at the page on the browser

Comment: when I swap this const path = item.image  const image = require(path) -- it falls down with a render error

Comment: @AndyGaskell any thoughts?

Comment: @TheOldCounty you need to find a path to your images that works. There's no way for me to know what that is. That's a web server configuration issue. If you can load one of the dynamic images by using a path like `<img src="/public/img/home/works_emp_01.png" />` you can modify the paths in your JSON programmatically before setting the `src` attribute.

Comment: Well I could modify the json path -- there is another idea here -- "Store the json in the state or a prop and then use it to render the image

const image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(json.image);"

Comment: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided